# How to get the Mailchimp member information with each list subscribtion status?

Tags: php, mailchimp

How to get the Mailchimp member information with each list subscribtion status?

```
$mailChimp = new MCAPI($this->api_key);
$listid = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$retval = $mailChimp->listMemberInfo( $listid, 'yourname@gmail.com' );

if ($this->_mailChimp->errorCode) {
   $error['Code'] = $this->_mailChimp->errorCode;
   $error['Message'] = $this->_mailChimp->errorMessage;
   return $error;
}

print_r($retval);
```

Return array:

```
Array
(
    [id]        => xxxxxxxxxx
    [email]     => yourname@gmail.com
    [email_type]=> html
    [ip_opt]    => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    [ip_signup] => 
    [member_rating] => 2
    [info_changed] => 2013-09-23 12:08:28
    [web_id]    => xxxxxxxx
    [merges]    => Array
        (
            [EMAIL]  => yourname@gmail.com
            [MERGE0] => yourname@gmail.com
            [FNAME]  => Firstname
            [MERGE1] => Firstname
            [LNAME]  => Lastname
            [MERGE2] => Lastname
        )

    [status]    => unsubscribed
    [timestamp] => 2013-09-23 12:08:28
    [lists]     => Array
        (
            [xxxxxxxxxx] => subscribed
            [xxxxxxxxxx] => subscribed
            [xxxxxxxxxx] => subscribed
        )
)
```

But here I don't know how to check that which List I have subscribed and Which is Unsubscribed. Because

```
[lists]     => Array
    (
        [xxxxxxxxxx] => subscribed
        [xxxxxxxxxx] => subscribed
        [xxxxxxxxxx] => subscribed
    )
```

Here all the lists are not match with my Original Lists Id getting list using

`lists()` method of Mailchimp

```
$retval = $mailChimp->lists();
```

Can anyone has idea how to check that `my email id: 'yourname@gmail.com'` has subscribed to this lists and unsubscribed to this list.

I want to know the status of each list by given `List_ID and Email_ID`

> I have used PHP as technology.

Comment: I found this method but it is not working.
`http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsforemail.func.php`
`listsForEmail(string apikey, string email_address)`

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but for future visitors:

For version 2 of the API (the `Mailchimp` class has `public $root = 'https://api.mailchimp.com/2.0';`), this works for me:

```
$MailChimp = new Mailchimp('YOUR_MAILCHIMP_API_KEY');
$lists = $MailChimp->helper->listsForEmail(array("email" => $email));
```

You'll need appropriate error checking; for example, it'll throw a `Mailchimp_List_NotSubscribed` if the email address isn't subscribed to any lists.